# Saving a full-res image from a zoom window?

Tags: html, image

sorry, newbie here.

I asked a question yesterday, but feel as though I structured it to be unanswerable. I'm trying to save a full-res image that displays in a zoom-window when I hover over a thumbnail image on Nike.net. In order to access Nike.net, you have to have login information, so I've attached a screenshot and the appropriate page elements. I've looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486900/how-to-get-a-full-res-image-from-an-amazon-zoom-window), but the setup is just a bit different.

IMAGES:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWmoQ.jpg)

LINKS:
[Small Image File](https://images2.nike.net/is/image/DPILS/727982-873-PHSFH001?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=jpeg&resMode=sharp2&defaultImage=eCommerceDefault)

HTML:

```
<img ng-src="https://images2.nike.net/is/image/DPILS/727982-873-PHSFH001?
wid=520&amp;hei=520&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;defaultImage=eCommerceDefault"
width="520" height="520" ng-if="viewType.name" class="ng-scope" 
src="https://images2.nike.net/is/image/DPILS/727982-873-PHSFH001?
wid=520&amp;hei=520&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;defaultImage=eCommerceDefault">
```

Thanks in advance!

/Keegan

Comment: I failed to add this element which is directly below the code ^^^.



<div class="zoom-highlight ng-hide" ng-show="detailsCtrl.zoom.showPan" ng-class="{ 'zoom-out' : detailsCtrl.zoom.showZoom }" ng-click="detailsCtrl.toggleZoom()" style="left: 443.794px; top: 182.707px; width: 62.1937px; height: 52.5865px;"></div>

Comment: What do you mean trying to save? like save it to your computer?

Comment: Yes sir! Save to my computer as an image file.

Comment: Can you not right click on the image and choose save as?

Comment: I can right-click to save as on the small preview of the image of the left; but I need a full-res version for my purposes. I cannot right click on the zoomed preview on the right to save-as.

Comment: can you right click on the image and get the link to it and open in a new tab then save it?

Answer (score -1):

using google chrome > right click and click Inspect > go to Application Tab > go to Images > look for the image in full-res > open in new tab and save